# Slide two pages to left and right using CSS or JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two "About" pages and would like to scroll left and right to each other when a link is clicked. This is my mark up.

```
<div id="about">
    <div id="about-1">
        <p>Content for about 1</p>
        <a href="#about-2">Slide to #about-2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="about-2">
        <p>Content for about 2</p>
        <a href="#about-1">Slide back to #about-1</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I also made a visual representation on how I want it to be:

[image]

I am new to this and was hoping I'd get a simple CSS solution as much as possible because I don't know JS/Jquery but if it's the simpler way, so be it. I would also like it to be responsive if that's not too much to ask. :) Help, anyone? Thanks!

Comment: what you have tried till now

Comment: I have tried following this: http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wtvaJ/2/ but am still having difficulties with it. Still trying, though. I just thought of asking a question as all of the solutions/examples I see are far more complicated than what I need.

Comment: mention your fiddle in question and what difficulties you are facing while using that, what error do you get

Comment: You fiddle looks fine to me .. its serves the purpose

Comment: What are dimensions? 100% (width and height), or...? Setup current CSS and HTML in fiddle, and you will get help fast, i am sure....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you thought about using JQuery UI?

Here is an example for you to have look at:

```
function transitionPage() {
    // Hide to left / show from left
    $("#about-1").toggle("slide", {direction: "left"}, 500);

    // Show from right / hide to right
    $("#about-2").toggle("slide", {direction: "right"}, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#about-1').click(transitionPage);
    $('#about-2').click(transitionPage);
});
```

[**FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/fs488b3r/5/)